# Oracle Java Json not working even after adding classpath

Tags: java, java-11

I am using openjdk version 11.0.15 on Debian 4.19. I want to use the JSON library available in Java: javax.json-1.0.jar. After downloading the jar file, I have added the classpath like so:

```
export CLASSPATH=/Diss/frontend/javax.json-1.0.jar

echo $CLASSPATH:
/Diss/frontend/javax.json-1.0.jar
```

my code is this:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonStructure;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

public class ns3_inputs {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
                JSONObject obj = new Json.createObjectBuilder();
                obj.add("foo", "bar");
                obj.build();
        }
}
```

I compile like this:  javac -cp .:$CLASSPATH ns3_inputs.java

to which I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        JSONObject obj = new Json.createObjectBuilder();
        ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class ns3_inputs
ns3_inputs.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        JSONObject obj = new Json.createObjectBuilder();
                                 ^
  symbol:   class createObjectBuilder
  location: class Json
2 errors
```

The java source code file and the jar file are in the same directory. Am I supposed to place the jar file in a specific path? I am very new to Java so I may be missing something very basic here. I am trying to build a desktop Java application and I cannot use any libraries suitable for android. Please suggest a solution

Comment: There is no class named `javax.json.JSONObject` defined in javax.json-1.0.jar.

Comment: There is also no `.build()` method on `JsonObject`.  That method is in `JsonObjectBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name is `JsonObject`, not `JSONObject`.

The following compilation is successful.

```
~ $ export CLASSPATH=~/Downloads/javax.json-api-1.0.jar 
~ $ 
~ $ cat ns3_inputs.java 
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;

public class ns3_inputs {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
                JsonObjectBuilder obj = javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder();
                obj.add("foo", "bar");
                obj.build();
        }
}
~ $ 
~ $ javac ns3_inputs.java
```